# How can I create an array in php with 20 rows and 20 columns and their values is 0?

Tags: php, arrays

As I know in php, let suppose a variable a is array

```
$a = array();
```

the array have keys and its value, and the count of keys is its range, so I thought I could make array in array:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)
{
    $b = array($i);
    $a = array($i=>$b);
}
print_r($a);
```

but I got --> Array ( [19] => Array ( [0] => 19 ) )

How can I create an array in php with 20 rows and 20 columns and their values is 0?

---

I used `array_fill` in php

So I fixed it

```
$b = array_fill(0,20,0);

$a = array_fill(0,20, $b);

print_r($a);
```

Thank you your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, hope it may also help you, as you have already resolved, but keep it in option if necessary:

```
<?php 
$a = array();
for($i = 0; $i<20; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j<20; $j++) {
        $a[$i][$j] = 0;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
?>
```

Hope, this may be useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

```
array_fill(0, 20, array_fill(0, 20, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below script

```
        $row_column_array = array();
        for($row = 0;$row < 20;$row++){
            for($column = 0;$column < 20;$column++){
                $row_column_array[$row][$column] = "$row-$column";
            }
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($row_column_array);
```

output : https://eval.in/747950

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it

```
$b = array_fill(0,20,0);

$a = array_fill(0,20, $b);

print_r($a);
```